# Connection must be valid and open -> Error occurs but connection is valid?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, mysql-connector

I have some problems with my database connection in my application.
My application stores some data into a mysql database and now I got the error mentioned in the title.

The problem is:
Right before I call the method that throws this exception I call another method which also connects to the database but successfully.
At first I thought that there is an error in my source but there is no error.

Here is the bad method:

```
public static bool checkExistence(object obj)
    {
        MySqlCommand checkQuery = new MySqlCommand(MySQLQueries.getCheckQueryByObject(obj), connection);
        object checkResult = null;
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            OpenConnection();
            try
            {
                checkResult = checkQuery.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler(ex);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandler(ex);
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            checkResult = checkQuery.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        if (checkResult != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

As you can see I first create a new command which later will check if an object exists.
The result of the query will be stored in `object checkResult` and at the end I simply check if `checkResult == null`.
Because of some problems with opening / closing the `connection` I decided to check if the connection is opened or not.
Now if the bad method is called the connection is closed.
Then after calling `OpenConnection()` the connection is opened again with the same settings as before.
As soon as the application executes `checkResult = checkQuery.ExecuteScalar();` the exception is thrown.

I really don't know what actually is the problem.
To ensure that the connection is valid from my point of view I put `connection` into the watchlist and tracked every change made to it by the application.
Nothing was different than in any other method that successfully used the database.

A friend of mine said that there might be a kind of optimization error while building the application.
He himself doesn't work with C# but sometime with C so it was just a vague guess.

Is there maybe any error in the code that I missed or any guess why this happens?

Thanks in advance!
Greetz

Edit: I use the latest version of MySQL's C# connector

Comment: Is this ASP.NET (or any other multi-threading app) and you're using Connection-Pooling? Then static connections which are not closed are a very bad idea.

Comment: No it's a WPF project and it isn't multithreaded.
I don't use Connection-Pooling afaik.

Comment: Fixed it. There was a problem with `OpenConnection()` and the MySQLCommand. After creating the MySQLCommand I call `OpenConnection()` and this method changes `connection` which is assigned to the already created command. I think the assigned connection is kind of invalid after changing it.